# Azure DevOps - What clone command to combine projects?

Tags: git, azure-devops

I am trying to reduce the number of projects we have in DevOps by creating multiple repositories where it makes sense.  However I am getting an error when importing another project repository.

1. In Project1, I go to "Import Repository"
2. In "Import a Git Repository", section "Clone URL", I added the clone command from Project2:

   > https://company1.visualstudio.com/Project2/_git/Project2
3. I entered my credentials (Requires authorization), clicked "Import"

I get error:

> Import request cannot be processed due to one of the following reasons:
>   Clone URL is incorrect.
>    Credentials are incorrect.
>   Clone URL points to an empty repository.

What am I doing wrong?

- Clone URL is valid, it resolves correctly in another browser window
- My credentials should be fine
- Both projects reside in the same team/company

Comment: What credentials are you using? Did you try using a PAT?

Comment: I own the team, so I used my email and password. I also tried PAT, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.  After creating a PAT, when I Import the Git repository, I have to enter both a Username and the PAT.  Because Username field did not have the "required" indicator, I kept excluding it, just using the PAT only.